# Rails 4 and Devise: add custom var at current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

How can i customize `current_user` adding an attribute like `current_user.array` ?

EDIT: better explaination 
I need to save the records ids of an associated table cause i dont wanna call the db every time a user visit a page like `products/1` to control if the product is associated at the `current_user`. With the ids i can do something like `if the array stored in session[:ids] contain params[:id] current_user can access to the page else redirect_to root_path`

Comment: What so you want to save / access in this array and where does the data come from?

Comment: I need to save the records ids of an associated table cause i dont wanna call the db every time a user visit a page like `products/1` to control if the product is associated at the `current_user`

Comment: This reads like you're trying to do some premature optimization. Don't worry about DB calls for things like this, a DB exists to be called, especially for things like this. Google a few articles on premature optimization and see what experiences other people have had.

Comment: Really thanks for the advice i'll take it in the future! But now i need to do what my boss tells me to do

Comment: How about asking your boss why he thinks this optimization could be necessary or speed up the app? Have you done any profiling, i.e. do you really know that these particular database calls are taking a long time?

Comment: In a future probably yes cause it's a big data! Soo we are going OT thanks for the help! bye

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `devise` `current_user` refers to the user currently logged in. By using `current_user.something` you can access the value stored in `something`. `something` could be a column in the user table or simply an attribute in the model for storing values.

If you want to store some values for the user only as long as the user is logged in, you can store it in session by using

```
session[:something] = #Value of something
```

You can access this value by using `session[:something]`.

Comment: Thanks for explanation. But if i try to add `session[:something] = "hello world"` in `sessions_controller.rb` and do `logger.info(session[:something])` he returns empty

Comment: That's strange! Try to use the value in a view for a logged in user.

Comment: Doesnt work it's empty...We are sure the value need to be declared in `class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController`?

Comment: No!! You add the value in the Controller not in the Class.

Comment: you mean the `application_controller.rb`?

Comment: yes, `application_controller.rb` or any other controller

Answer (score 1):

`current_user` is just a [Devise helper](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers) for the attributes of the currently signed-in `user`

Adding extra attributes to the object this helper represents will have to be done through the `User` model:

```
#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
end

#-> current_user.profile.image
```

Comment: That's true but surelly i have not explained enough my issue. I edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Why do you use the session? It is already associated with the current user. For example
Try this in your controller:

```
session[:array] = #something...
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the attribute to your user model

Answer (score 0):

You can access the columns in th users table using current_user, but the attributes must be accessible.

```
 current_user.name  where name is in the users table and it is attr_accessible in User.rb
```